# cPanel 20GB+ file compression and downloading issue taken too much time

Tags: cpanel

In my cpanel, threre is 30GB Project file, i am trying to compress it and downloading
but unfortunatly, file compression is taken too much time.

can you suggest any efficient way to compress it and can download easily